# Dynamically create Groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures, jenkins-groovy

I have the need to dynamically create closures which should call other closures within itself.

Here is an example of what I expect the resulting code to do

```
Closure execute = {
  println("First")
  Closure second = {
    println("Second")
    Closure third = {
      println("Third")
    }.call()
    println("Second")
  }.call()
  println("First")
}

execute.call()
```

The above results in the following output:

```
First
Second
Third
Second
First
```

How can I create the above closure code dynamically given the following list:

```
List<String> commands = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, lets make a function which returns a closure

```
def wrap(String name, Closure cl = null) {
    { ->
        println(name)
        // If we were passed a closure, then run it and print the name again
        if (cl) {
            cl()
            println(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, take our list of commands

```
List<String> commands = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

And store the current closure in a variable

```
Closure current = null
```

Then, lets go backwards through the list, creating a new closure, and wrapping the previous one

```
commands.reverse().each {
    current = wrap(it, current)
}
```

Then we can run the final closure:

```
current()
```

And we get the output:

```
First
Second
Third
Second
First
```

In non-jenkins groovy you can use inject instead of the each with a mutating variable:

```
Closure current = commands.reverse().inject(null) { curr, command ->
    wrap(command, curr)
}
```

But in my experience of answering Jenkins questions, `inject` rarely works, so stick with the first way

Comment: This works for me. I am curious to know what does the following block do?


   { ->

   }

Comment: `{ -> }` That's a closure that takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can store closures in variables and store those variables in a list

```
Closure first = {
    println("First")
}

Closure second = {
    println("Second")
}

Closure third = {
    println("Third")
    second()
}

List<Closure> execute = [first, second, third]

execute*.call()
```

Output:

```
First
Second
Third
Second
```